# Is there an app for OS X that can do something like Google's similar image search using images local drives as the database to serch in?

Tags: quicklook

Reading about this a little it seems the compute power required is rather intense, but this would be a very useful app for finding old image files, even from their quicklook previews in the case of Adobe files like INDD, AI, PS.

Comment: Quick look previews are generated "live" from the actual document, so they wouldn't help. Try it with a multi-layer PS pic & all you get is a blank square.

Comment: Yeah true, Apple stopped Quartz Composer files previewing in Quicklook around Mountain Lion, considering them a security risk :-) (they can access keyboard and cameras etc amongst other things)

Comment: My main use case would be JPEGs, PNGs, PDFs I think in which case QT previews might suffice. Otherwise whole file, or if thumbs are big enough use those. Doesn't seem like theres an app out there that can do anything like this though for OS X.